# How to get ahold of the EventID and use it to get the actual time for a gpu to process a kernel?

Tags: c, opencl

Probably one of the more straight forward and quick answer questions here on the forums.  I'm working on an openCL project and I'm trying to find a way to get ahold of the eventID in order to use getEvent() to find out the time it took the GPU to process the image (I'm working on image convolution).  Does anybody know of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the commands that start with clEnqueue can return a cl_event (or more accurately, can fill in the contents of a cl_event that you pass in the address of). That is the typical way of creating an event that you can later inquire timing values from.

So, declare a cl_event object, then pass its address as the last parameter to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, then after the kernel is done running (you could use clFinish or wait on the event), call clGetEventProfilingInfo with the cl_event and ask for CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START and then CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, subtract them to get the execution time. Note: the command queue will have to have profiling enabled (include CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE flag set in properties argument to
clCreateCommandQueue) for this to work.

Finally, be sure to clReleaseEvent or you'll leak memory.